# How to update add a new tabPanel in moduleServer for a tabsetPanel created in moduleUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I try to add a new tabPanel in module server for a tabsetPanel created in moduleUI  but it doesnt work. The server know very well which tab is shown but still can't add a new tab to it. How can i solve this problem ?

In the main ui and main server, i created a tabsetPanel and a button to add newtab for it and it works well. But when i try to do the same thing inside a module it doesnt work any more.

```
library(shiny)
## create a tabset Panel in module environment
tabModuleUI <- function(id, title){
  ns = NS(id)
  return(
    tabPanel(title = title, value = id,
             shinydashboard::box(width = NULL,
                                 tabsetPanel(id = ns("Product_module"),
                                        tabPanel(title = "Product 0", value = "Product 0"),
                                        tabPanel(title = "Product 1", value = "Product 1")),
                                 ## button to add new tab
                                 actionButton(inputId = ns("button"), label = "Click")))
  )
}
tabModuleServer <- function(input, output, session, idModule){
 ns <- session$ns
 id_num = reactiveVal(1)
 parentSession <- get("session", envir = parent.frame(1))
 observeEvent(input$button,{
   id_chr = paste("Product_module", id_num())
   # server know which tab is shown
   print(input[["Product_module"]])
   # but cannot add a newtab in it
   appendTab(inputId = "Product_module", tab = tabPanel(title = id_chr, value = id_chr, 
                                                 shinydashboard::box()), 
             session = session)
   # even when i add a ns to inputId
   appendTab(inputId = ns("Product_module"), tab = tabPanel(title = id_chr, value = id_chr,
                                                     shinydashboard::box()), session = session)
   # but it can add a newtab in global environment
   appendTab(inputId = "Product", tab = tabPanel(title = id_chr, value = id_chr,
                                                            shinydashboard::box()), session = parentSession)
   id_num = id_num(id_num()+1)
  })
}

## create a tabsetPanel in global environment

ui <- fluidPage(title="",
                tagList(tabsetPanel(
                               id = "Product",
                               tabPanel(title = "Product 0", value = "Product 0"))),
                ## button to add new tab
                actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "Click"))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  id_num = reactiveVal(1)
  observeEvent(input[["button"]],{
    id_chr = paste("Product", id_num())
    # server know which tab is choosen
    print(input[["Product"]])
    # add add a newtab to it
    appendTab(inputId = "Product", tab = tabModuleUI(id = id_chr, title = id_chr), select = T)
    callModule(tabModuleServer, id = id_chr, idModule = id_chr)
    id_num = id_num(id_num()+1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: This problem comes from the fact that I used an id contain a space. To prevent ce type of error, you can replace paste by paste0. That works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
library(shiny)
### create a tabset Panel in module environment
tabModuleUI <- function(id, title){
  ns = NS(id)
 return(
    tabPanel(title = title, value = id,
             shinydashboard::box(width = NULL,
                                 tabsetPanel(id = ns("Product_module"),
                                             tabPanel(title = "Product_module 0", value = "Product_module 0") #,
                                             #tabPanel(title = "Product 1", value = "Product 1")
                                 ),
                                 ## button to add new tab
                                 actionButton(inputId = ns("button"), label = "Click Module")))
  )
}
tabModuleServer <- function(input, output, session, idModule){
  ns <- session$ns
  id_num = reactiveVal(1)
  parentSession <- get("session", envir = parent.frame(1))
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    id_chr = paste0("Product_module", id_num())
    # server know which tab is shown
    print(input[["Product_module"]])
    print(input$button)
    ### but cannot add a newtab in it
    appendTab(inputId = ns("Product_module"), tab = tabPanel(title = id_chr, value = id_chr,
                                                         shinydashboard::box()), session = parentSession)
    # ### even when i add a ns to inputId
    # appendTab(inputId = ns("Product_module"), tab = tabPanel(title = id_chr, value = id_chr,
    #                                                          shinydashboard::box()), session = session)
    ### but it can add a newtab in global environment
    # appendTab(inputId = "Product", tab = tabPanel(title = id_chr, value = id_chr,
    #                                               shinydashboard::box()), session = parentSession)
    id_num = id_num(id_num()+1)
  })
}

## create a tabsetPanel in global environment

ui <- fluidPage(title="",
                tagList(tabsetPanel(
                  id = "Product",
                  tabPanel(title = "Product 0", value = "Product 0"))),
                ## button to add new tab
                actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "Click Main")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  id_numm = reactiveVal(1)
  observeEvent(input[["button"]],{
    id_chr = paste0("Product", id_numm())
    # server know which tab is choosen
    print(input[["Product"]])
    # add add a newtab to it
    appendTab(inputId = "Product", tab = tabModuleUI(id = id_chr, title = id_chr), select = T)
    callModule(tabModuleServer, id = id_chr, idModule = id_chr)
    id_numm = id_numm(id_numm()+1)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Please note that tab panels within module will reset unless you retain the previous values.